# How to implement let* in scheme?

Tags: scheme

I am trying to learn scheme and trying to implement interpreter for let* in scheme. Here is the grammar:

```
<s6> -> <expr>                   
       | <define>
<expr> -> NUMBER | IDENT | <if> | <let> | <letstar> | <lambda> | <application>
<define> -> ( define IDENT <expr> )
<if> -> ( if <expr> <expr> <expr> )
<let> -> ( let ( <var_binding_list> ) <expr> )
<letstar> -> ( let* ( <var_binding_list> ) <expr> )
<lambda> -> ( lambda ( <formal_list> ) <expr> )
<application> -> ( <operator> <operand_list> )
<operator> -> <built_in_operator> | <lambda> | IDENT
<built_in_operator> -> + | * | - | /
<operand_list> -> <expr> <operand_list> | empty
<var_binding_list> -> ( IDENT <expr> ) <var_binding_list> | ( IDENT <expr> )
<formal_list> -> IDENT <formal_list> | IDENT
```

I have learned how to implement let before, here it is:

```
(define let-stmt? (lambda (e)
(and (list? e) (equal? (car e) 'let) (= (length e) 3))))

(define get-value (lambda (var env)
(cond
    ((null? env) (error "s6-interpret: unbound variable -->" var))
    ((equal? (caar env) var) (cdar env))
    (else (get-value var (cdr env))))))

(define s6-interpret (lambda (e env)     //thanks to GoZooner
(cond
    ((number? e) e)
    ((symbol? e) (get-value e env))
    ((not (list? e)) (error "s6-interpret: cannot evaluate -->" e))

    ((let-stmt? e)
        (let ((names (map car  (cadr e)))
                (inits (map cadr (cadr e))))

        (let ((vals (map (lambda (init) (s6-interpret init env)) inits)))

        (let ((new-env (append (map cons names vals) env)))

        (s6-interpret (caddr e) new-env)))))
```

How can i modify interpreter for let so that i can write an interpreter for let*? Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked several times recently, scroll down in the list of Scheme questions. Here's the gist of it: `let*` is a syntactical transformation, read more about this subject in [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1), look for the section titled "Derived expressions". The key idea for this case is that whenever your evaluator finds an expression such as this:

```
(let* ((a 10)
       (b (+ 10 a)))
  (+ a b))
```

... You can directly transform it into an equivalent series of nested `lambda` applications, which can be easily evaluated like this:

```
((lambda (a)
   ((lambda (b)
      (+ a b))
    (+ 10 a)))
 10)
```

Alternatively, you can perform an intermediate step and first transform a `let*` into a series of nested `let`s and then evaluate them - this is useful in case you already have implemented the `let` special form. The same example above would look like this:

```
(let ((a 10))
  (let ((b (+ 10 a)))
    (+ a b)))
```

Of course, first you have to know how to evaluate a `lambda` form. The whole point here is, that both `let` and `let*` are special forms (nothing more than syntactic sugar) that don't follow the same evaluation model of, say, a procedure application, and need a special treatment at the evaluator level - in this case, a syntactical transformation that produces a different expression that we know how to evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

Know that:

```
(let* ((a ...) (b ...) (c ...)) body ...)
```

is equivalent to:

```
(let ((a ...))
  (let ((b ...))
    (let ((c ...))
      body ...)))
```

(see [R5RS](http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/r5rs.pdf), page 44, `(define-syntax let* ...)`). Now, given this, and knowledge that:

```
  (let ((a ...)) body ...)
```

is equivalent to:

```
  ((lambda (a) body ...) ...)
```

the 'expansion' of the `let*` that I showed above becomes:

```
  ((lambda (a)
     ((lambda (b)
        ((lambda (c)
           body ...)
          <c-init>))
      <b-init>))
   <a-init>)
```

Answer (score 1):

From [R5RS](http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/r5rs.pdf), Section 7.3:

```
(define-syntax let*
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((let* () body1 body2 ...)
      (let () body1 body2 ...))
    ((let* ((name1 val1) (name2 val2) ...) body1 body2 ...)
      (let ((name1 val1))
        (let* ((name2 val2) ...)
          body1 body2 ...)))))
```